# How does this transpose function work?

Tags: f#

I have this function given by my professor and I have no idea what is actually happening.

Here is the function that computes the transpose of an m-by-n matrix:

```
let rec transpose = function
| [] -> failwith "cannot transpose a 0-by-n matrix"
| []::xs -> [] 
| xs -> List.map List.head xs :: transpose (List.map List.tail xs)
```

Testing the function:

```
> transpose [[1;2;3];[4;5;6]];;
  val it : int list list = [[1; 4]; [2; 5]; [3; 6]]
```

I understand List.map, recursion and all that stuff. I just do not understand why/how this function works. Any clarifications will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say we have a 3x3 matrix `A`.

```
let A = 
  [ [1;2;3]
    [4;5;6]
    [7;8;9] ]
```

> ```
> = [ R1
>     R2
>     R3 ]
> ```

Now, let's analyse the transpose function.

```
let rec transpose = function
| [] -> failwith "cannot transpose a 0-by-n matrix"
| []::xs -> [] 
| xs -> List.map List.head xs :: transpose (List.map List.tail xs)
```

The first 2 cases catch the events where:

- the list is an empty list
- the list contains an empty list, meaning all inner lists have been processed

The code [1]

```
List.map List.head xs
```

maps the inner lists to their respective head elements

> ```
> R1.Head ; R2.Head ; R3.Head
> = 1 ; 4 ; 7
> = C1
> ```

The code [2]

```
transpose (List.map List.tail xs)
```

(recursivly) transposes the tails of the beheaded lists. 
So on each recursion a column gets transposed into a row.
Using the `::` keyword these rows are then used to construct the resulting list.

> ```
> transpose A
> = C1 :: C2 :: C3 :: []
> = [ C1
>     C2
>     C3 ]
> = [ [1;4;7]
>     [2;5;8]
>     [3;6;9] ]
> ```

Comment: Thank you! That was a spot on explanation!