# Sorting indexes in list of lists - F#

Tags: f#, iteration, sublist

Currently I have a function to return the first elements of each list (floats), within a list to a separate list.

```
let firstElements list =
    match list with
    | head::_ -> head
    | [] -> 0.00
```

My question is, how do I expand this to return elements at the same index into different lists while I don't know how long this list is? For example

```
let biglist = [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]]
```

If I did not know the length of this list, what is the most efficient and safest way to get

```
[[1;4;7];[2;5;8];[3;6;9]]
```

Comment: Seems like a group by would be the way to go.

Comment: That looks like what you're actually trying to do is transposing a matrix; maybe look into algorithms for that. (If I understood that correctly, FSharp.Core will contain a function for that in the future.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does this transpose function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574032/how-does-this-transpose-function-work)

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev it is already there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the recent added `List.transpose` function. But it is always good to be good enough to create such functions yourself. If you want to solve the problem yourself, think of a general algorithm to solve your problem. One would be.

1. From the first element of each list you create a new list
2. You drop the first element of each list
3. If you end with empty lists you end, otherwise repeat at step 1)

This could be the first attempt to solve the Problem. Function names are made up, at this point.

```
let transpose lst =
    if allEmpty lst 
    then // Some Default value, we don't know yet
    else ...
```

The `else` branch looks like following. First we want to pick the first element of every element. We imagine a function `pickFirsts` that do this task. So we could write `pickFirsts lst`. The result is a list that itself is the first element of a new list.

The new list is the result of the remaining list. First we imagine again a function that drops the first element of every sub-list `dropFirsts lst`. On that list we need to repeat step 1). We do that by a recursive call to `transpose`.
Overall we get:

```
let rec transpose lst =
     if   allEmpty lst
     then // Some Default value, we don't know yet
     else (pickFirsts lst) :: (transpose (dropFirsts lst))
```

At this point we can think of the default value. `transpose` needs to return a value in the case it ends up with an empty list of empty lists. As we use the result of `transpose` to add an element to it. The results of it must be a `list`. And the best default value is an empty list. So we end up with.

```
let rec transpose lst =
    if   allEmpty lst
    then []
    else (pickFirsts lst) :: (transpose (dropFirsts lst))
```

Next we need to implement the remaining functions `allEmpty`, `pickFirsts` and `dropFirsts`.

`pickFirst` is easy. We need to iterate over each element, and must return the first value. We get the first value of a list by `List.head`, and iterating over it and turning every element into a new list is what `List.map` does.

```
let pickFirsts lst = List.map List.head lst
```

`dropFirsts` need to iterate ver each element, and just remove the first element, or in other words keeps the remaining/tail of a list.

```
let dropFirsts lst = List.map List.tail lst
```

The remaining `allEmpty` is a predicate that either return true/false if we have an empty list of lists or not. With a return value of `bool`, we need another function that allows to return another type is a list. This is usually the reason to use `List.fold`. An implementation could look like this:

```
let allEmpty lst   = 
    let folder acc x =
        match x with
        | [] -> acc
        | _  -> false
    List.fold folder true lst
```

It starts with `true` as the default value. As long it finds empty lists it returns the default value unchanged. As soon there is one element found, in any list, it will return `false` (Not Empty) as the new default value.

The whole code:

```
let allEmpty lst   = 
    let folder acc x =
        match x with
        | [] -> acc
        | _  -> false
    List.fold folder true lst

let pickFirsts lst = List.map List.head lst
let dropFirsts lst = List.map List.tail lst


let rec transpose lst =
    if   allEmpty lst
    then []
    else (pickFirsts lst) :: (transpose (dropFirsts lst))


transpose [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]]
```

Another approach would be to turn it into a 2 dimensional mutable array. Also do length checkings. Do the transformation and return the mutable array again as an immutable list.

Comment: THIS is much better answer than mine. Take the biggest upvote from me. StackOverflow should be proud

Answer (score 3):

`List.transpose` has been added recently to FSharp.Core

```
let biglist = [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]]

let res = biglist |> List.transpose

//val res : int list list = [[1; 4; 7]; [2; 5; 8]; [3; 6; 9]]
```