# Transposing nested lists in F#

Tags: list, f#, nested, transpose

I would like to transpose a nested list (`'a list list`) in F#. Problem is, I don't want to use recursion.

However, I have found that in order to not use recursion I must use mutable lists. In my mind, this is a bit problematic. Nonetheless, I have tried to implement it with a for-loop and two mutable lists:

```ml
let transpose (llst : 'a list list) : 'a list list =
   let mutable lst = llst
   let mutable result = [List.map List.head lst]
   for i = 1 to lst.Length do
      lst <- List.map List.tail lst
      result <- List.append result [List.map List.head lst]
   result
```

Moreover, I have tried avoiding it. I know the mutability of arrays, so I have tried to solve the problem by converting from `'a list list` to 2darray (`[,]`), however, when trying to convert the result back to a nested list, it fails, as `List.ofArray` only works with 1D arrays:

```ml
let transpose (llst : 'a list list) : 'a list list = [List.ofArray (Array2D.init (llst.ToArray.GetLength 1) (llst.ToArray.GetLength 0) (fun x y -> llst.ToArray.[y,x]))]
```

The first code works, but I would like a more simple implementation with no for-loops or mutable lists.
The second code does not work, as the function `List.ofArray` only works with `[]`, not `[,]`.

I have also tried with

```ml
List.init (llst.[0].Length) (List.forall (fun SOMETHING) llst)
```

Where the `SOMETHING` will include a function that takes the first column of both sublists, and then drops the first column. (List.map List.head and List.map List.tail). Maybe with the use of `List.map`?

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is to take a recursive definition and translate it to non-recursive. For example, the following recursive definition is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574032/how-does-this-transpose-function-work) with the tweak that it uses list comprehensions:

```
let rec transpose xs = [
  match xs with
  | [] -> failwith "cannot transpose a 0-by-n matrix"
  | []::xs -> () 
  | xs -> 
      yield List.map List.head xs 
      yield! transpose (List.map List.tail xs) ]
```

This is tail-recursive, which makes it very easy to translate to a loop. You just make the parameter `xs` mutable and replace recursive call with mutation. We also need to add a flag to terminate the loop:

```
let rec transpose xs = [
  let mutable xs = xs
  let mutable finished = false
  while not finished do
    match xs with
    | [] -> failwith "cannot transpose a 0-by-n matrix"
    | []::_ -> finished <- true
    | _ -> 
        yield List.map List.head xs 
        xs <- List.map List.tail xs ]
```

If you wanted a mutable version without sequence comprehensions, you can easily do that - the comprehension is just collecting the individual sublists that you add using `yield`. You can prepend those to a mutable list instead (and then reverse the list to get the results in the right order):

```
let rec transpose xs = 
  let mutable result = []
  let mutable xs = xs
  let mutable finished = false
  while not finished do
    match xs with
    | [] -> failwith "cannot transpose a 0-by-n matrix"
    | []::_ -> finished <- true
    | _ -> 
        result <- (List.map List.head xs) :: result
        xs <- List.map List.tail xs 
  List.rev result
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I would prefer to not use ANY mutable values. Maybe I could use List.init to make a nested list. Sort of like
```f#
let transpose (llst : 'a list list) : 'a list list = List.init (llst.[0].Length) (List.init (fun (TRANSPOSE))
```
I think that would be a very good and minimalist implementation, but I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am grateful for the reply, but what I was really after was how to make the simplest and most compact function to transpose a list of list. I have now come up with a some-what weird implementation. Though compact, I think it is rather complex:

```ml
let transpose (llst: 'a list list) : 'a list list = 
List.map (List.map List.head) (List.init llst.Head.Length (fun x -> List.fold (fun x f -> f x) llst (List.init x (fun x -> (List.map List.tail)))))
```

Can be made more simple with some subfunctions, but I is funny how such a weird implementation works. Thank you.

Comment: There is really nothing simple about this. It is just compact, and I would almost call it obfuscated. It is also fragile, and possibly wrong. It will crash on an empty list, for example. It can certainly be fun to toy around with ideas like this, but please do not ever write this kind of code where someone else might have to understand it. I know you probably never intended to, but there are people who actually think code like this is good, so this is a warning directed towards them. If you write code like this, I will find you, and I will look very sternly in your direction!

Comment: $glennsl I completely agree with all you have written, and obviously, the best way to go about transposing a list of lists in F# would be by recursively mapping. This code does not work in all cases, nor is readable/understandable, but it does work in the most simple and normal situations. Given that I wanted a non-recursive function with no mutables (variables), I think this is the most compact solution.